# Import Users into Projects - How to grant access to Document Management top folders for Member user? (Autodesk Forge API)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I'm referencing specifically the [Autodesk Forge BIM 360 API, Project Users, POST users/import (v2) endpoint](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/users-import-POST/).

Drilling down into the body request services options, it seems like there are only two options for user permissions.

1. Full Admin access on both project administration and document management.
2. User (Member) access on document management.

Lately we've noticed that with option #2, the user can't see the top folders when they navigate to Document Management on that project.
[image: Partial screenshot showing the message, "Welcome to Document Management. Once documents have been shared with you, they will appear here."]

**Questions**

A) Has it always been this way and we are just now noticing, or is there a bug?

B) Is there any way via the API to extend permission to the top folders for these users or does it have to be manually adjusted? I have hunted through the documentation and come up empty-handed so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be as design because folder permissions have not been assigned to the user. Folder permissions need to be assigned and recognized for the member. Check Folder Permissions for instructions on how to add permissions to project members, or try the endpoint to assign permission to the user/role/company by https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/document-management-projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-permissionsbatch-create-POST/, both should work fine.

You can check the link for the details:
https://www.autodesk.com/support/technical/article/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/BIM-360-Docs-Team-member-unable-to-access-folders-despite-having-the-correct-permissions.html

Comment: Thanks! This was the information I needed.